# Please suggest me a way to FindElements from this html tag

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way extract using the `data-bind` value or `data-xid` in this snippet:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="35" data-bind="value: firstGivenName" data-xid="firstGivenName"/>.
```

Comment: @cFrozenDeath I guess the question should be: why is it tagged with `javascript`? `C#` + `selenium` + `FindElements` in the title - all make sense together.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Comment: You probably should add some more details on what you are looking for. Are you looking to identify the element using those values or are you looking to extract those values from a given element?

Answer (score 2):

Locate the `input` element and use [`.GetAttribute()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_GetAttribute.htm) to get the attribute value:

```
IWebElement myInput = Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[data-xid][data-bind]"));
myInput.GetAttribute("data-xid");
```

If you are asking about finding the element based on the `data-xid` attribute value:

```
IWebElement myInput = Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[data-xid=firstGivenName]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with JQuery.

```
var elements_found = $("input[dataxid='firstGivenName']")
```

Comment: Please look at how the question is tagged: C# and Selenium. Plus, `FindElements()` in the title gives a hint this is selenium-specific.

Comment: It says JavaScript as well.. :) @alecxe